# want to clean up and change unicode form fields in using rails model in a more DRY way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, unicode, dry

**Currently I am using this to strip out whitespaces.**

```
class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :clean_up_whitespace
end


def clean_up_whitespace 

fields_to_strip = ['title','notes']
 fields_to_strip.each { |f|
   unless self.attributes[f].nil?
      self.attributes[f].strip!
   end
 }
end
```

---

**I want to do something similar for getting rid of MS word type of unicode.
Currently I use:**

```
require 'iconv'

class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :clean_up_unicode
end

def clean_up_unicode

unless title.blank?
    self.title = Iconv.iconv('ascii//ignore//translit', 'utf-8', self.title).to_s
  end

  unless notes.blank?
    self.notes = Iconv.iconv('ascii//ignore//translit', 'utf-8', self.notes).to_s
  end
end
```

---

This method works but is not very DRY since I need to do it for 40 some form fields.

**I had thought I could use something like:**

```
require 'iconv'

class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :clean_up_unicode
end

def clean_up_unicode 

unicode_fields_to_clean = ['title','notes']
   unicode_fields_to_clean.each { |u|
    unless self.attributes[u].blank?
       self.attributes[u] = Iconv.iconv('ascii//ignore//translit', 'utf-8', attributes[u]).to_s
   end
 }
end
```

I know I am not understanding something with the way this works.
when I replace
 
 
*self.attributes[u] =*
 
with
 
*puts some_variable =*
 
I get the correct output to the console. I just don't know how to get that variable back to the form.

If it helps the code that is wrong is **self.attributes[u] =** I don't know what to replace it with. I would have thought I could use *self.VariableNameOfField =* but rails does not recognise the variable being used directly like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so with some help from:
**John Topley** and **Jakob S** 
*(sorry as a new user cannot only have 1 hyperlink and thus cannot link to their stack-overflow profiles)*

And asking a simpler [stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000482/in-rails-how-do-i-update-form-fields-in-the-model)

I have been able to come up with the following code that works.
The trick was changing.

```
self.attributes[u] = Iconv.iconv('ascii//ignore//translit', 'utf-8', attributes[u]).to_s
```

**to**
    self.send("#{u}=", Iconv.iconv('ascii//ignore//translit', 'utf-8', attributes[u]).to_s)

**The Working Code**

---

```
require 'iconv'

class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :clean_up_unicode
end

def clean_up_unicode 

unicode_fields_to_clean = ['title','notes']
   unicode_fields_to_clean.each { |u|
    unless self.attributes[u].blank?
       self.send("#{u}=", Iconv.iconv('ascii//ignore//translit', 'utf-8', attributes[u]).to_s)
   end
 }
end
```