# In Rails how do I update form fields in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model

Let's pretend I want to set all the fields I specify to be = "frog"

In the model I can set each one manually using:

```
self.field1 = 'frog'
self.desc_field = 'frog'
self.fieldx = 'frog'
etc....
```

But how can I this by putting the field names in an array?

When I try

```
fields_array=['field1','desc_field','fieldx']    
fields_array.each { |field|    
  self.field = 'frog'
}
```

It does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the end result you're trying to achieve? You probably don't want this sort of code in a controller.

Comment: Yes, Actually code is in model, thanks I updated the question. Actually wanting to clean out ms word unicode from form. Asked the question here stackoverflow.com/questions/998555/ But seems like people were overwhelmed by the full question, because no one answered. so thought someone might answer if it was in a simpler form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Topley's answer above is basically correct, however since you want to assign values you want to doing something like:

```
fields_array=['field1','desc_field','fieldx']    
fields_array.each { |field|    
  self.send("#{field}=", 'frog')
}
```

Note the added equal sign. With that you're doing `self.field1='frog'` rather than `self.field1('frog')`.

Comment: Good catch. I wasn't sure of the exact syntax for assignment and don't have a Ruby interpreter at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `send` method:

```
fields_array=['field1','desc_field','fieldx']    
fields_array.each { |field|    
  self.send("#{field}", 'frog')
}
```

Comment: Action controller comes back with this error  "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)"